# Passing value to other package's program and call other package's program in current program in java

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working on a a java project. I'm using eclipse with java 1.7.  I wish to pass a variable value (string) to another program stored in other folder

```
                         main Proj
                         /       \
                  folder1        folder2
                 /       \             \
         prog1.java   prog2.java       prog3.java
```

I have a variable, say `msg` of string type in prog2.java.

(1) I need to pass its value from prog2.java to prog3.java (note in other folder).

(2) Also, i wish to know how to call prog3.java in prog2.java. I do not want to separately run prog3.java, but then I run prog2.java, the prog3.java can automatically run.

(3) Can I make `msg` a private variable in java?

Can someone help how to achieve these tasks.

Comment: @gonzo The project has confidential issues and a large project. I cannot post the content here. I'm able to pass value to other program in the same package. However, I'm not able to pass the value to a program in other package. I tried to import packagename.classname in the current program. It didn't work.

Comment: So are your folders in the diagram packages?

Comment: yes, the scenario is exactly as I have shown above.

Comment: Is what you're trying to access `private`, `protected`, or package-private (no modifier)?

Answer (score 1):

You can access a public method or public field from a public class (both have to be public in this case) from whatever package you want as long as it is part of the same project. You do this with `import`. Here are a couple of example classes.

This is some random class with a main method. It is in the package "folder2".

```
package folder2;
public class prog2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Printing from package: folder2");
    }
}
```

Another class in a different package, "folder1", and calling the above main method. Notice the `import` statement.

```
package folder1;
import folder2.prog2;  //Syntax is packageName.className
public class prog1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        prog2.main(args); // Calling main method from another package
    }
}
```

The output when you compile `prog1.main`.

```
Printing from package: folder2
```

Hope this helps.